# How can Javascript automatically assign a value to an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm creating a JavaScript object - "obj".
I want to be able to put into it ( obj.value1 = "text1" and obj.value2 = "text2" )
If I only create obj.value1 = "text1", obj.value2 should be automatically created with value1

I do not know how to do that. Possibly with get and set, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: *"Possibly with get and set, but it doesn't work for me"* That's how you'd do it. What did your code trying to do that look like? (Alternatively you could use a Proxy around the object.)

Comment: Use proxy and reflect. see this [jsconf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5X2aB_mNp4)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a getter to use value1 if value2 isn't set

```js
class MyClass {
  #_value2;

  constructor(value1, value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
  }
  
  set value2(value) {
    this._value2 = value;
  }
  get value2() {
    return this._value2 || this.value1;
  }
}

const myClass1 = new MyClass('text1', 'text2');
const myClass2 = new MyClass('text1');

console.log(myClass1.value2, myClass2.value2);
```